# How to get a DataGridViewColumn by it's HeaderText Property?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, headertext

How do I get a column of a data grid view by the header text rather than by the index or name property?

What I tried so far is the my intuitive approach:

```
// Identifiers used are:
string myHeaderText = "Header Text";

dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView.Columns[myHeaderText];
```

however this returns

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: You can use lambda or a simple loop but the result may be null or non-unique..: `int index = -1;
string column = "xyz";
var cols = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(x => x.HeaderText == column).ToList();
if (cols.Count == 1) index = cols.First().Index;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is returning

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

because

```
dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView.Columns[myHeaderText];
```

is looking for a column in the the dataGridView with a **Name** Property = myHeaderText not **HeaderText** property. To get around this you could try the following:

```
namespace Extensions
{
    // Class for: DataGridView Extensions
    public static class DataGridViewExtension
    {
        // Method for: Getting the DataGridViewColumn by the header text
        public static DataGridViewColumn IndexByHeaderText(this DataGridView dataGridView, 
            string headerText)
        {
            // Identifiers used are:
            DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
            int columnIndex;

            // Get the index (using LinearSearch, at worst O(n), could sort for better)
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
            {
                // Check if the header text is found
                if (column.HeaderText == headerText)
                {
                    columnIndex = column.Index;
                    return dataGridView.Columns[columnIndex];
                }
            }

            // Return if not found
            return dataGridViewColumn;
        }
    }
}
```

this creates an extension method to DataGridView